# Error on update query symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine, dql

I generated the CRUD for the entity Evenement(event) , which is working. But now I want to update a field in another entity called notification everytime an Evenement is added. Each Evenement has a categorie

Evenement.php:

```
<?php

namespace Mql14\mqlmeBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;


/**
 * Mql14\mqlmeBundle\Entity\Evenement
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="evenement")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Evenement
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $nom
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
     */
    private $nom;

    /**
     * @var datetime $date
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @var string $description
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", length=400, nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var integer $ticket
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Ticket", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $ticket;

    /**
     * @var User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="evenement")
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @var Categorie
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Categorie", inversedBy="evenement")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="categorie_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $categorie;

    /**
     * @var Lieu
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Lieu")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="lieu_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $lieu;

   public function __construct()
    {
        $this->user = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set nom
     *
     * @param string $nom
     */
    public function setNom($nom)
    {
        $this->nom = $nom;
    }

    /**
     * Get nom
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getNom()
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }

    /**
     * Set date
     *
     * @param datetime $date
     */
    public function setDate($date)
    {
        $this->date = $date;
    }

    /**
     * Get date
     *
     * @return datetime 
     */
    public function getDate()
    {
        return $this->date;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Set ticket
     *
     * @param integer $ticket
     */
    public function setTicket($ticket)
    {
        $this->ticket = $ticket;
    }

    /**
     * Get ticket
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getTicket()
    {
        return $this->ticket;
    }

    /**
     * Add user
     *
     * @param Mql14\mqlmeBundle\Entity\User $user
     */
    public function addUser(\Mql14\mqlmeBundle\Entity\User $user)
    {
        $this->user[] = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * Set categorie
     *
     * @param Mql14\mqlmeBundle\Entity\Categorie $categorie
     */
    public function setCategorie(\Mql14\mqlmeBundle\Entity\Categorie $categorie)
    {
        $this->categorie = $categorie;
    }

    /**
     * Get categorie
     *
     * @return Mql14\mqlmeBundle\Entity\Categorie 
     */
    public function getCategorie()
    {
        return $this->categorie;
    }

    /**
     * Set lieu
     *
     * @param Mql14\mqlmeBundle\Entity\Lieu $lieu
     */
    public function setLieu(\Mql14\mqlmeBundle\Entity\Lieu $lieu)
    {
        $this->lieu = $lieu;
    }

    /**
     * Get lieu
     *
     * @return Mql14\mqlmeBundle\Entity\Lieu 
     */
    public function getLieu()
    {
        return $this->lieu;
    }




    public function getCategorieId(\Mql14\mqlmeBundle\Entity\Categorie $categorie)
    {
        $idc= $categorie->getId();
        return $idc;
}

}
```

Categorie.php:

```
<?php

namespace Mql14\mqlmeBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Mql14\mqlmeBundle\Entity\Categorie
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="categorie")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Categorie
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $nomcat
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nomCat", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
     */
    private $nomcat;

    /**
     * @var string $photo
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="photo", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
     */
    private $photo;

    /**
     * @var $evenement
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Evenement", mappedBy="categorie")
     */
     private $evenement;

    /**
     * @var User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="categorie")
     */
    private $user;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->user = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set nomcat
     *
     * @param string $nomcat
     */
    public function setNomcat($nomcat)
    {
        $this->nomcat = $nomcat;
    }

    /**
     * Get nomcat
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getNomcat()
    {
        return $this->nomcat;
    }

    /**
     * Set photo
     *
     * @param string $photo
     */
    public function setPhoto($photo)
    {
        $this->photo = $photo;
    }

    /**
     * Get photo
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPhoto()
    {
        return $this->photo;
    }

    /**
     * Add user
     *
     * @param Mql14\mqlmeBundle\Entity\User $user
     */
    public function addUser(\Mql14\mqlmeBundle\Entity\User $user)
    {
        $this->user[] = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * Add evenement
     *
     * @param Mql14\mqlmeBundle\Entity\Categorie $evenement
     */
    public function addEvenement(\Mql14\mqlmeBundle\Entity\Evenement $evenement)
    {
        $this->evenement[] = $evenement;
    }

    /**
     * Get evenement
     *
     * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getEvenement()
    {
        return $this->evenement;
    }
}
```

Notification.php:

```
<?php

namespace Mql14\mqlmeBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Mql14\mqlmeBundle\Entity\Notification
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="notification")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Notification
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $etat
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="etat", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $etat;

    /**
     * @var User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="User_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *
     * })
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @var Categorie
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Categorie")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Categorie_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *
     * })
     */
    private $categorie;



    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set etat
     *
     * @param string $etat
     */
    public function setEtat($etat)
    {
        $this->etat = $etat;
    }

    /**
     * Get etat
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getEtat()
    {
        return $this->etat;
    }

    /**
     * Set user
     *
     * @param Mql14\mqlmeBundle\Entity\User $user
     */
    public function setUser(\Mql14\mqlmeBundle\Entity\User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return Mql14\mqlmeBundle\Entity\User 
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * Set categorie
     *
     * @param Mql14\mqlmeBundle\Entity\Categorie $categorie
     */
    public function setCategorie(\Mql14\mqlmeBundle\Entity\Categorie $categorie)
    {
        $this->categorie = $categorie;
    }

    /**
     * Get categorie
     *
     * @return Mql14\mqlmeBundle\Entity\Categorie 
     */
    public function getCategorie()
    {
        return $this->categorie;
    }
}
```

In the createAction that was generated after the execution of the CRUD for the Evenement entity I added the update query :

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $entity  = new Evenement();
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $form    = $this->createForm(new EvenementType(), $entity);
    $form->bindRequest($request);
    $entity->upload();
  $cat=$entity->getCategorie();


if ($cat) {
    $catn = $cat->getNomCat();


$query = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager()->createQuery( 'UPDATE Mql14mqlmeBundle:Notification n SET n.etat=1  WHERE n.categorie LIKE :catn  ' );
          $query->setParameter('categorie', $catn);
            $query->execute();

  }
if ($form->isValid()) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $em->persist($entity);
    $em->flush();

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('mql14mqlme_adminshow', array('id' => $entity->getId())));

}

return array(
    'entity' => $entity,
    'form'   => $form->createView(),            
);
```

}

And the error I'm getting is this:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 61 near 'categorie LIKE': Error:
>   Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.

Answer (score 0):

You set the wrong parameter in the update query.

On this line:

```
$query = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager()->createQuery(
         'UPDATE Mql14mqlmeBundle:Notification n SET n.etat=1
         WHERE n.categorie LIKE :catn' );
      $query->setParameter('categorie', $catn);
        $query->execute();
```

It should be:

```
$query = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager()->createQuery(
         'UPDATE Mql14mqlmeBundle:Notification n SET n.etat=1
         WHERE n.categorie LIKE :catn' );
      $query->setParameter('catn', $catn);
        $query->execute();
```

Comment: oops I didn't see that, but I corrected it and it's still giving me the same error

Comment: I would like to add that in my database (because I generated the entities from a database) in the table notation I hace the column "Categorie_id" wich represents the id of the categorie, so I don't know if database's column are in a dql oor not or do we just do the queries on the entities.

Answer (score 0):

`n.categorie` is an entity (of type `Mql14\mqlmeBundle\Entity\Categorie`) and you can't compare entities using `LIKE`.

Try replacing `LIKE` with `=`.

Change

```
UPDATE Mql14mqlmeBundle:Notification n SET n.etat=1 WHERE n.categorie LIKE :catn
```

To

```
UPDATE Mql14mqlmeBundle:Notification n SET n.etat=1 WHERE n.categorie = :catn
```

Comment: FuzzyTree I tried your solution but the update is not happening, but instead I used a raw sql query and now it's working for me.$count = $conn->executeUpdate("UPDATE Notification SET etat = 1 where Categorie_id=$catn");

Comment: If `$catn` is an id and not an entity try `WHERE IDENTITY(n.categorie) = :catn`.